# swift - is it possible to create a keypath to a method?

Tags: swift

Is it possible to create a keypath referencing a method? all examples are paths to variables.

I'm trying this:

```
class MyClass {
    init() {
        let myKeypath = \MyClass.handleMainAction
        ...
    }
    func handleMainAction() {...}
}
```

but it does not compile saying `Key path cannot refer to instance method 'handleMainAction()`

Comment: What are you trying to achieve here? You can just say `let fn = handleMainAction` to get a function variable of type `() -> Void`, which you can pass about and call. Just beware of retain cycles; the method is partially applied with `self`, so will keep it retained as long as the function reference is kept alive.

Comment: Is this your actual code? How can I duplicate the issue? Please - include actual code!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

KeyPaths are for properties.  However, you can do effectively the same thing.  Because functions are first class types in swift, you can create a reference to handleMainAction and pass it around:

```
//: Playground - noun: a place where people can play

import UIKit
import XCTest
import PlaygroundSupport

class MyClass {
    var bar = 0

    private func handleMainAction() -> Int {
        bar = bar + 1
        return bar
    }

    func getMyMainAction() -> ()->Int {
        return self.handleMainAction
    }
}

class AnotherClass {
    func runSomeoneElsesBarFunc(passedFunction:() -> Int) {
        let result = passedFunction()
        print("What I got was \(result)")
    }
}


let myInst = MyClass()
let anotherInst = AnotherClass()
let barFunc = myInst.getMyMainAction()

anotherInst.runSomeoneElsesBarFunc(passedFunction: barFunc)
anotherInst.runSomeoneElsesBarFunc(passedFunction: barFunc)
anotherInst.runSomeoneElsesBarFunc(passedFunction: barFunc)
```

This will work fine, and you can pass "barFunc" to any other class or method and it can be used.

Answer (score 6):

You can use `MyClass.handleMainAction` as an indirect reference. It gives you a block that take the class instance as the input parameter, and returns corresponding instance method.

```
let ref = MyClass.handleMainAction  //a block that returns the instance method
let myInstance = MyClass()
let instanceMethod = ref(myInstance)
instanceMethod()                    //invoke the instance method
```

The point is you can pass around / store the method reference just like what you did with a key path. You just need to supply the actual instance when you need to invoke the method.

Comment: This is really useful, as it's not possible to `weak`en a function that has a partial application of an instance already on it. This way, you can ensure that the instance used is weak until you need it, especially if you're in UI glue code where you're trying not to hang on to models.